# Large File handling in Python

Tags: python, file

I am doing some file operations in python. I am using python version Python 3.5.2.
I have a large file of 4GB. And I'am reading the file in chunk say, 2KB.

I have a doubt.
If the any 2KB chunk happens to be in the middle of line (in between 2 newlines) will that line be truncated or the half-read lines' contents be returned ?

-Regards,

Comment: Did you code anything?

Comment: Yes, this is a problem; it you just read 2K at a time and break things into lines, you need to keep the "overflow" from the last buffer to concatenate to the start of the next one. But the good news is that the built-in file objects in Python already do this for you. Just do `for line in file:`, and it will buffer things up, handle the overflow, and just give you a line at a time, without ever reading more than about a page into memory.

Comment: @RafiGoldfarb No. I guess this is more of a theoretical doubt.

Comment: @abarnert : Thanks for the clarification. But reading each line at a time, will this not consume lots of time ? Instead I searching for some thing like:
( read chunk of 2KB.) or (the previous line <if 2KB lies in middle of line>)

Comment: If you're worried about performance, write it both ways and test. Under the covers, it's reading a nice optimal amount into a buffer, splitting things into lines pretty quickly, doing the overflow without the extra copies from the naive way, and yielding lines. For many special cases, you can come up with something faster than that, but you'd need to explain what your special case is. For example, sometimes the answer is `re` over `mmap`, but in other cases that's a terrible answer.

Comment: Also, often (no longer _always_ with modern systems—e.g., you could be running on a slow mobile CPU or a shared cloud server but reading off a RAM disk…), reading 2K at a time off a disk is so the slow part, so optimizing anything else barely even matters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a problem. You can see that with a much smaller test:

```
s = io.BytesIO(b'line\nanother line\nanother\n')
while True:
    buf = s.read(10)
    if not buf: break
    print('*** new buffer')
    for line in buf.splitlines():
        print(line.decode())
```

The output is:

```
*** new buffer
line
anoth
*** new buffer
er line
an
*** new buffer
other
```

As you can see, the first buffer has a truncated partial line that finishes in the next buffer, exactly what you were worried about. In fact, this will happen not just *occasionally*, but _most of the time).

The solution is to keep around the overflow (after the last line) from the old buffer, and use it as part of the new buffer. You should try to code this up for yourself, to make sure you understand it (remember to print out the leftover overflow at the end of the file).

But the good news is that you rarely need to do this, because Python file objects do it for you:

```
s = io.BytesIO(b'line\nanother line\nanother\n')
for line in s:
    print(line.decode(), end='')
```

That's it. You can test this with a real file from `open(path, 'rb')` in place of `BytesIO`, it works just as well. Python will read in about a page at a time, and generate lines one by one, automatically handling all the tricky stuff for you. If "about a page" isn't good enough, you can use something more explicit, e.g., passing `buffering=2048` to the `open` function.

In fact, you can do even better. Open the file in text mode, and Python will still read in about a page at a time, split it into lines, and decode them for you on the fly—and probably a lot more efficiently than anything you would have come up with:

```
for line in open(path):
    print(line, end='')
```